# Why does the shell expand a quoted "$@" as multiple parameters

Tags: string, shell, sh, posix, parameter-expansion

The following command prints `foo bar`, as expected:

```bash
sh -c 'printf "$@"' -- "foo bar"
```

However, when called with `foo` and `bar` as separate arguments, it only prints `foo`:

```bash
sh -c 'printf "$@"' -- foo bar
```

(`sh` and `bash` have the same behavior here)

This indicates to me that the expression `"$@"` is turned into multiple parameters, leading to a call of `printf foo bar`, instead of `printf "foo bar"`.

1. Why is this the case? I thought that quotes denote a single string?
2. How can i change the `sh -c` command to get the desired behaviour (`printf "foo bar"`)
   when passing multiple arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this the case?

Because `$@` is special.

> I thought that quotes denote a single string?

Not in the case of `$@`.

> How can i change the sh -c command to get the desired behaviour (printf "foo bar") when passing multiple arguments?

You can use `"$*"` to join arguments with space (first character from IFS).

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02 :

> 2.5.2 Special Parameters
>
> @
> [...] When the expansion occurs within double-quotes [...] the initial fields shall be retained as separate fields [...]

Comment: Thank you for the documentation link, that's exactly what I was looking for.
Since I'm a little out of depth here, could you clarify one additional thing for me:
Would there any difference between `$@`
and `"$@"`  in this context then?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment: figured it out myself. With `$@`, the individual fields will undergo further field splitting,
with `"$@"` they won't. So `"$@"` is correct and necessary for forwarding args. (https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0040)